# How to partition array in-place in C with O(n) algorithm?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

I want to partition an array of integers so that negative values are to the left of positive values, and I want to do this in-place (no additional auxiliary memory). Note that the array must not sort from small to low, just collect negatives to the left and positives to the right.

I have created a naive function that has time complexity O(n^2), but wonder how you would go about solving it in linear time? My algorithm uses two pointers that start pointing to the leftmost and rightmost elements of the array. When ptr1 encounters a positive value, and ptr2 encounters a negative value, we perform a swap, the pointers iterate right/left and when they meet, the function returns because the array is finished collecting.

Could you help me think of a simpler algorithm to do this collecting?

```
int* swaps(int* array){

    int* ptr1;
    ptr1 = &array[0];
    int* ptr2;
    ptr2 = &array[N-1];
    int tmp;


    for(ptr1; ptr1 <= &array[N-1]; ptr1++){
         if(ptr1==ptr2){
             return array; 
         }
         if(*ptr1 >= 0){
             for(ptr2; ptr2 >= &array[0]; ptr2--){
                if(ptr1==ptr2){
                  return array; 
                }

                // swap elements
                if(*ptr2 < 0){
                tmp = *ptr2;
                *ptr2 = *ptr1;
                *ptr1 = tmp;
                ptr2--;
                if(ptr1==ptr2){
                   return array; 
                }
                break;
                }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you discover an `O(n)` sorting algorithm, they'll probably name a bunch of universities after you.

Comment: @0jnats3 I think you mean for(ptr1; ptr1 < ptr2; ptr1++){ and for(ptr2; ptr2 > ptr1; ptr2--){ The complexity of the algorithm is O( n ).

Comment: there is no reason to write `for (ptr1;` - you do not need to write absolutely anything there before the first colon.

Comment: In any case the complexity is still `O(n)`  because `ptr2` is always decremented for each element and `ptr1` incremented, so voting to close this...

Comment: @Blaze I might've used the word "sort" too freely here. I should reiterate that, I want to only collect values, not sort. So input "1 0 -2 -1" will  actually result to "-1 -2 0 1" for this specific input

Comment: i.e. "sign sort" or "sort using `nonnegative(x)` as the key function"

Comment: What you want is a linear-time _partition_, not sort. Essentially writing a C version of [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) from C++, which is already linear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a linear-time *partition*, not sort. Essentially writing a C version of [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) from C++, which is already linear.

A sample C++ implementation is linked, but it's easy enough to translate. Quick sketch:

```
/*
 * Quick translation of C++ std::partition<int*>.
 *
 * You just need to write the helper functions
 *
 *     int* find_first_positive(int *array, size_t length)
 *     -- should return array+length if they're all negative
 *
 *     void swap(int*, int*)
 *     -- just exchange the two integers
 */
void sign_partition(int *array, size_t length)
{
    int *last = array + length;
    int *first = find_first_positive(array, length);
    if (first == last) return; /* all negative, nothing to do */

    /* now search for negative values after the first positive */
    for (int *i = first + 1; i != last; ++i) {
        if (*i < 0) {
            swap(i, first);
            ++first;
        }
    }
}
```

The only trick is to notice that

1. before you enter the loop, every element in the half-open interval `[array,first)` is negative, by definition (it's the first positive value you found)
2. every time you find a negative value out of place, and after you exchange it with `*first` and increment the pointer, this condition holds again (so far as you currently know).

   That is, the interval `[array, i)` is always partitioned at the start of the loop, and `[array, i]` is always partitioned by the end of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially for describing a loop invariant for testing the correctness of your algorithm.

Comment: Sorting and partitioning algorithms are for some reason very prone to giving code that looks _too_ simple to work, until you sit down and think very carefully about the invariants at each step. I find writing them out explicitly helps me believe!